# Object is possibly 'undefined' in set state method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react and don't know what is wrong with my code. The compiler prints out that this.state.ticketsToShow is possibly undefined

> Object is possibly 'undefined'.  TS2532

Here is my code.

```
handler = (id: string) => {
        this.setState({
            ticketsToShow: this.state.ticketsToShow.length > 0 ? this.state.ticketsToShow.filter(t => t.id !== id) : this.state.ticketsToShow
        });
      };
```

```
state: AppState = {
        ticketsToShow: []
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example :

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

        class Example extends Component {

         state = {
           ticketsToShow: [{id: 1, name: 'Deepankar'}, {id: 2, name: 'Bob'}]
          }

            handler = (id: string) => {
              this.setState({
                ticketsToShow: this.state.ticketsToShow.length > 0 ? this.state.ticketsToShow.filter(t => t.id !== id) : this.state.ticketsToShow
              });
            };
}
```

Comment: when I try this it writes that this.state.ticketsToShow Object is possibly 'undefined' how to fix it?

Comment: in this case it adds random tickets what I do not want to do and it didn't solves the problem this.state.ticketsToShow Object is still possibly 'undefined'

Comment: edit question according your need. I'll try answering

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is warning you that may not have initialized an object before making a reference to it.

You've not shown in your question how `this.state` is initialized, but I would guess that it is likely that this is causing the warning, i.e. the way you're instantiating that property leaves the possibility that that the property is undefined when you access it.

For example, both of these examples will generate the warning:

```
class State {}

class ABC {
    state: State | undefined = new State()
}

class ABC {
    state?: State = new State()
}
```

The solution is either to declare the instance in such a way that it is definitely defined, or alternatively wrap your code referencing the instance in a check for undefined, e.g.

```
if (this.state) {
    // do stuff with state
}
```

Looking at the comments on your post, it appears that `ticketsToShow` is the offending property. The same comments above still apply, you'll need to look at how it is initialised or wrap it in a check for `undefined`.

Comment: how could I initialize state in this case?

Comment: You'll need to provide a more complete example of how are you initializing state at the moment. i.e. in your code you've reference this.state, but it's not clear what the context of 'this' is. Is the code executing in the instance of a class? Worth reading the guidelines on providing a minimal and complete example for your post.